# How to preserve order of appearance when counting words in a word list file

Tags: text-processing

I have two files:

- `file1` contains a list of unique words
- `file2` contains several sentences

I want to output a tab separated file with the occurrence of each word in listed in `file1` in `file2` *while preserving the order in which they are listed in file 1*.

For example:

- `file 1`:

  ```
  dog 
  apple
  cat
  ```
- `file 2`:

  ```
  the dog played with the cat and the cat was white.
  the boy ate the apple.
  ```
- Desired output:

  ```
  dog 1
  apple 1
  cat 2
  ```

I tried existing [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928918/count-occurrences-of-a-list-of-words-in-a-text-file) in the community, but they all sort the output.

Comment: In your example you should include some non-trivial cases like `dog-fish` and `pineapple` and contiguous words like `dog dog` in file2 and at least 1 case in file1 that doesn't appear in file2, e.g. `rabbit`. If you only show trivial sunny day cases in your example then you greatly increase your chances of getting an answer that only works for trivial sunny day cases.

Comment: @EdMorton  I liked "sunny day". When I saw the comment asking about Arabic, I liked it all over again.

Comment: @M.A.G  Don't **significantly** change any question (e.g. by introducing non-latin words) after you got answers and it's not clear if "output" is the output you want that you don't get or output you get that you don't want. I rolled this back as it was before you got answers, just ask a new followup question if you have other character sets to consider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using any POSIX awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
NR==FNR {
    words[NR] = $1
    next
}
{
    $0 = " " $0 " "
    gsub(/[^[:alpha:]]+/,"  ")
    for ( i in words ) {
        word = words[i]
        cnts[word] += gsub(" "word" ","&")
    }
}
END {
    for ( i=1; i in words; i++ ) {
        word = words[i]
        print word, cnts[word]+0
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
dog     1
apple   1
cat     2
```

The above assumes that "word"s are all alphabetic characters and that you want the matches to be case-sensitive or the input is all lower case as in your example and that the words in file1 are unique as in your example.

Comment: Thank you! I have edited my question though, what if punctuation exists and non latin words (Arabic)?

Comment: Then ask a new followup question.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

Below is a general solution for matching lines of one file (saved as `@a` array) against lines of a second file (saved as `@b` array), counting occurrences (i.e. `Bag`ging):

```perl
raku -e 'my  @a =  dir(test => "alphabet.txt").IO.lines.reverse; my @b = $*ARGFILES.lines;  \
         for @a -> $a {@b.grep(/<$a>/).Bag.pairs.say};'  alphabet.txt alphabet.txt
```

In constructing `@a`, Raku is given a `dir()` location and a `test => "…"` filename. In constructing `@b`, one-or-more files are entered on the command line, and read off via Raku's `$*ARGFILES` dynamic variable.

**General Input** is `alphabet.txt`, one letter per line and reversed immediately upon reading into Raku to place the array in "z".."a" order;

**General Output** (when two copies of  "a".."z" `alphabet.txt` are entered on the command-line):

```
(z => 2)
(y => 2)
(x => 2)
(w => 2)
(v => 2)
(u => 2)
(t => 2)
(s => 2)
(r => 2)
(q => 2)
(p => 2)
(o => 2)
(n => 2)
(m => 2)
(l => 2)
(k => 2)
(j => 2)
(i => 2)
(h => 2)
(g => 2)
(f => 2)
(e => 2)
(d => 2)
(c => 2)
(b => 2)
(a => 2)
```

Note how the return stays in the same order as the `@a` array, and how Raku doesn't require a `sort` call to produce the output above.

Finally, solving the OP's issue, all that has to be changed from the code above is using `my @b = $*ARGFILES.lines.words` instead of `my @b = $*ARGFILES.lines`.

*[To obtain tab-separated output use `.put` instead of `.say` in the code above. This drops the surrounding  parens and the `=>` arrow between the two columns].*

Final Code:

```
~$ raku -e 'my @a = dir(test => "dog_apple_cat.txt").IO.lines.grep(*.chars);  \
            my @b = $*ARGFILES.lines.words; for @a -> $a {  \
            @b.grep(/<$a>/).Bag.pairs.put};' text.txt
dog 1
apple.  1
cat 2
```

https://docs.raku.org/type/Bag
https://raku.org